# how to set key field as dynamic in select2 dropdown using angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

> i want to run dynamic data through ng-repeat and set dynamic key
>   values, like below,

**in directive scope:**
K
                optionKey : '@',
                optionValue : '@'

**in my template:**

```
<option ng-repeat="tag in dirData" value="{{tag.optionKey}}">{{tag.optionValue}}</option>
```

now i want to get options depending on dynamic optionKey & optionValue value data

Comment: Don't just ask for code...

Comment: i'm not asking code..i want to clear the issue..